# scanning from a file and saving the content in a string in c

Tags: c, file

How should I be scanning the content of a txt file and save it in a string. I have a model of a ship in ascii. The format of the txt file looks like this.

```
   /\
  |  |
 /    \
|______|
#
     .'|
   .'  |
 .'    |
'--..__|
#
   __.--'¯.
.¯¯     .'
 '.   .'
   '.'
#
```

I would like to jump over the # symbol and save the next ship in a new pos in the array.

```
FILE *file = fopen("...","r");
    char *shipModel[20][20];
    int ModelNo = 0;
    int line = 0;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if(file != NULL) {
        while(fscanf(file, "%s", shipModel[ModelNo][line]) != EOF){
            ////
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
```

this is all I have.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Is there a reason why would you store them in a file instead of just storing the "pictures" in a simple string?

Comment: I have a lot more models and the code would look messy if I just copy-paste them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bare-bones solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ship {
        char size[20][20];
} ship;

int main (void)
{
        FILE *file = fopen("ship", "r");
        int shipNo = 0;
        int row = 0;
        int NSHIPS = 5;   // num of ships - should be dynamic
        char line[20];

        ship shipModel[NSHIPS];

        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

        if (file != NULL) {
                while (fgets (line, 20, file)) {
                        if (line[0] != '#') {
                                strcpy (shipModel[shipNo].size[row], line);
                                ++row;
                        } else {
                                row = 0;
                                ++shipNo;
                        }
                }
        }
        // Print the first (0th) ship
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
                printf ("%s", shipModel[0].size[i]); 
        }

        fclose(file);
}
```

Garbage characters will be printed after a ship is printed as the 2-D array has not been zeroed out.

Comment: ```while (fgets (line, "%s", file)) {``` is this in the correct format? because I get lots of errors.

Comment: @Stephano. My bad. Updated.